# Is it possible in Android Studio to replace all occurences of a field by its assignment using hotkeys?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

For example I have the following code:

```
private String tabTitleSettings;

private void fillUINames() {
    tabTitleSettings = Local.get(LKey.Key_settings_tab);
}
```

And somewhere this code:

```
tabSpec.setIndicator(tabTitleSettings);
```

How can I replace a field by its assignment, using shortcut or using some other automated way?

I want achieve this result:

```
tabSpec.setIndicator(Local.get(LKey.Key_settings_tab));
```

**EDIT:**

I have found the easiest way for now...

Tap on field in this code:

```
private void fillUINames() {
    tabTitleSettings = Local.get(LKey.Key_settings_tab);
}
```

then tap on jellow bulb and choose "Moove assigment to a field declaration".

After I get this code:

```
private String tabTitleSettings = Local.get(LKey.Key_settings_tab);
```

and automatically removed tabTitleSettings field in fillUINames() method:

```
private void fillUINames() {
}
```

So then I just press on tabTitleSettings declaration field and press ctr + r and replace all occurences of

```
tabTitleSettings
```

with

```
Local.get(LKey.Key_settings_tab)
```

But it still too many oparations... Maybe somebody know how to do it faster?

Comment: select the field and shift+alt+r , Then you can refactor(rename) the field ,If i get the question right .

Comment: Super easy way is to to in `find and replace`, select entire `module` or `project`, and then simply write above first code in `find` and second code in  `replace` area and you should be good to go

Answer (score 4):

Press Ctrl+f, input field will come in front  and type what you want to replace. And then  press ctrl+r and type what you want to replace with. It will ask you to replace current occurence and all occurence. Press on all occurences it will do what you want in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to search and replace - Edit->Find->Replace in Path... Find all occurrences of tabTitleSettings in a project and replace it with desired value.